# How to synchronize(d) methods and modify objects' properties within a parent object?

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading

I have two threads running from a controller class. The first thread receives SMS messages and should continue running as long as the program is in the started state. The other thread is used to calculate the units GPS location.

The controller launches the SMS thread and waits from a text message. If a text message meets certain criteria, the GPS location thread is launched and coordinates are sent back to the controller.

For each thread, I've used the following format:

```
reader = new Reader(this);
        new Thread(reader).start();
```

The reader class then uses a reference of the controller so it can call a method in the controller:

```
public void ReceivedCommand(String address) {
    [..]
}
```

This method then creates an instance of the GPS thread which itself calls a method from the parent object (thread?) called `ReceivedLocation` which then sets up the new SMS message (`TextMessage` object). The problem is that the SMS thread can only return the original sender's address (to reply to) and I need to use the GPS thread so I can set the Payload for the SMS message.

So now I have 2 methods using the same object (`TextMessage` object), but I want to ensure that the first method (SMS address setter) doesn't change the address while the GPS thread is getting the GPSLocation to set.

Can synchronizing a block within `ReceivedCommand()`:

- Add the address to the `TextMessage` object,
- Run the GPS thread
- Let the GPS thread call the second method (`ReceivedLocation()`)
- And let that method change the TextMessage object?

Comment: I've edited my answer about 50 times now - probably worth another read. Note that synchronizing your `TextMessage` object's methods is not always enough - there may be *atomic* operations you want to control (i.e. a `compareAndSet`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, thread creation is expensive. You might be better off using a **thread pool** (as can be found in the `java.util.concurrent` package (an `ExecutorService`) and farming off your work to that

Using `synchronized` on a shared object will ensure that no two threads can be *inside* a `synchronized` block *at the same time*. However, if I create and start a thread within a `synchronized` block, I (i.e. the first thread) may have exited the block before the second thread actually starts:

```
final TextMessage msg = //...
Thread t = new Thread(r);
synchronized (msg) {
    t.start();
} //the other thread is still running and now this thread has not synchronized on the msg
```

Then your processor r:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (msg) { //only any use if readers are alse sync-ed
            msg.setGpsLocation(findGpsLocation(msg)); 
        }
    }
}
```

As long as the `TextMessage` object is thread-safe (i.e. field access is `synchronized`) you should be OK and *there is no need to explicitly synchronize in this way*.

> Note that `synchronized` is semantically important not just from the perspective of thread-scheduling but also from the fact that **[it affects data visibility between threads](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html)** (for example, without synchronization, you cannot be sure that modifications made in one thread will be visible to another).

Modifying my answer to use an `ExecutorService`:

```
final TextMessage msg = //...
ExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();
Future<?> f = worker.submit(r); //the future represents the work
```

Here, `r` would look like:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        GpsLocation  loc = findGpsLocation(msg);
        msg.setGpsLocation(loc); //the setter is synchronized
    }
}
```

It is the `setGpsLocation` method that should be `synchronized` (along with the `getter` and any other field access *required by both threads*). Note that simply sync-ing field access is not always enough if you require atomicity across fields. For example you may want to update one field conditionally on the value of another - in this case, as long as you `synchronize` explicitly during the field access, all will be OK:

```
synchronized (msg) {
    if (msg.getGpsLocation().isIn(AMERICA))
       msg.append(" DUDE!")
}
```